# argparse: optional argument between positional arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I want to emulate the behavior of most command-line utilities, where optional arguments can be put anywhere in the command line, including *between* positional arguments, such as in this `mkdir` example:

```
mkdir before --mode 077 after
```

In this case, we know that `--mode` takes exactly 1 argument, so `before` and `after` are both considered positional arguments. The optional part, `--mode 077`, can really be put *anywhere* in the command line.

However, with `argparse`, the following code does not work with this example:

```
# mkdir.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--mode', nargs=1)
parser.add_argument('dirs', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Running `./mkdir.py before --mode 077 after` results in:

```
mkdir.py: error: unrecognized arguments: after
```

How can I get `argparse` to accept an optional argument (with a fixed, known number of items) between positional ones?

Comment: To be precise, it's not "most" utilities, it's the ones that use a library doesn't treat the first non-optional argument as an end to the options (such as GNU `getopts`).

Comment: `argparse` doesn't support this style.

Comment: Related: [Optional positional arguments with Python's argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51227098/674039) and [Allow positional command-line arguments with nargs to be seperated by a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50916124/674039)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing), it seems `argparse` now supports this kind of Unix-style parsing:

> ### Intermixed parsing
>
> `ArgumentParser.parse_intermixed_args(args=None, namespace=None)`
>
> A number of Unix commands allow the user to intermix optional arguments with positional arguments. The `parse_intermixed_args()` and `parse_known_intermixed_args()` methods support this parsing style.

There is a caveat, but for "simple" options, it does not affect them:

> These parsers do not support all the argparse features, and will raise exceptions if unsupported features are used. In particular, subparsers, `argparse.REMAINDER`, and mutually exclusive groups that include both optionals and positionals are not supported.

*(I posted this FAQ-style question after spending 1 hour trying to understand why the examples in the Python `argparse` documentation didn't seem to include it, and only by chance found a somewhat unrelated question which contained the mention to this "intermixed" function in a comment, which I am unable to find again to cite it properly.)*

Comment: This parser is a bit of a kludge, operating 'on top of' the regular `parse_known_args`.  It 'deactivates' the positionals, parses the optionals, and separately handles the "extras".  See the methods' code for details.  As noted it was added with version 3.7 as a new feature.  It does not modify regular parsing.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not familiar with argparse so I would write my own code to handle arguments.

```
import sys

#the first argument is the name of the program, so we skip that
args = sys.argv[1:]
#just for debugging purposes:
argsLen = len(args)
print(args, argsLen)

#Create a list that will contain all of the indeces that you will have parsed through
completedIndeces = []
i = 0

#add the index to the completed indeces list.
def goToNextIndex(j):
    global i
    completedIndeces.append(j)
    i += 1

def main():
    global i
    ###core logic example
    #Go through each item in args and decide what to do based on the arugments passed in
    for argu in args:
        if i in completedIndeces:
            print("breaking out")
            #increment i and break out of the current loop
            i += 1
            # If the indeces list has the index value then nothing else is done.
            pass 
        elif argu == "joe":
            print("did work with joe")
            goToNextIndex(i)
        elif argu == "sam":
            print("did work with sam")
            goToNextIndex(i)
        elif argu == "school":
            print("going to school")
            goToNextIndex(i)

            # If the argument has other arguments after it that are associated with it 
            # then add those indeces also to the completed indeces list. 
    
            #take in the argument following school
            nextArg = i
            #Do some work with the next argument
            schoolName = args[nextArg]
            print(f"You're going to the school called {schoolName}")
            #make sure to skip the next argument as it has already been handled
            completedIndeces.append(nextArg)
        else:
            print(f"Error the following argument is invalid: {argu}")
            goToNextIndex(i)


    print(f"Value of i: {i}")
    print(f"completed indeces List: {completedIndeces}")

main()
```